# Is there a difference between "is proportional to" and "is a function of"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

If I say that $J$ (the volume current density) is proportional to $s$, the distance from the center axis of a long cylindrical wire, I can say that as $s$ changes, so does $J$.

I feel as though I could say the same thing as $f(x)=x^2$. As $x$ changes, $f$ also changes (according to the specified relationship, $x$ raised to the power of $2$).

Could someone help me clarify?

Comment: "$x$ is proportional to $y$" means there is a constant $k$ such that $x=ky$. It is not merely a matter of "as $x$ changes, $y$ does too."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that some quantity $J$ is proportional to another quantity $s$ is equivalent to the statement that there exists some unspecified constant $k$ such that
$$
J = ks.
$$
This is the same as saying that $J(s)$ is the function $J(s)=ks$, so *proportional to* implies *is a function of*. However, a general function $J(s)$ need not satisfy a proportionality relation. For example,
$$
J(s) = e^s
$$
is an example where $J$ is *a function of* $s$, yet $J$ is not *proportional to* $s$. Hence, being *proportional to* is a strictly stronger statement than *being a function of*.

Answer (score 3):

[Proportionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)) implies a linear relationship.

A function is much more general. The function $f(x) = x^2$ is quadradic, not linear.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!